# Expression Design 4 export for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, svg, windows-phone-8.1, adobe-illustrator

Of all the methods to get our Illustrator files into pretty XAML, I've found that using Expression Design 4 makes the nicest vectors for me.

However, this is not the case when using WinRT libraries, such as those in my Windows Phone 8.1 project.

Exporting as WPF Resource Dictionary uses libraries that can't be found. Of course, the Silverlight exports also don't work.

i.e. With the WPF Resource Dictionary I get:

```
The type 'GeometryDrawing' was not found.
The type 'DrawingGroup' was not found.
The type 'DrawingBrush' was not found.
Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.
```

i.e. With the Silverlight I get:

```
The text associated with this error code could not be found.
Failed to assign to property 'Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement.Clip' because the type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.PathGeometry' cannot be assigned to the type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.RectangleGeometry'.
```

Taking an Illustrator to SVG and then to XAML seems like a worse option.

Has anyone found a way around using their of these two as options?
Or another way using Expression Design?
Or another tool etc?

tia

Comment: I use Mike Swanson's [AI to XAML](http://www.mikeswanson.com/xamlexport/) export plugin with Illustrator CS5 and it generally does great for my needs. I'd recommend it. Another one I use occasionally is [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) which you can export to xaml with also.

Comment: @ChrisW., i've tried that, also doesn't give me 8.1/RT support, but seems to fail less. Maybe i'll post the libraries it can't find for light on their equivalents.

Comment: Uh, Path Geometry for vectors is pretty universal in most cases. Depending on how complex your vectors are you shouldn't have so much issue if you're exporting as silverlight xaml. If anything, you could draw stuff up in Blend and it will target whatever project you have open in it.

Comment: Path Geometry isn't available for the WinRT libs and making manual changes is too much effort. I guess it's too soon to expect tools with 8.1/WinRT Phone support. Blend also says it's wrong.

Comment: That's not true, I've worked with it before and know for a fact I use Path data. You could try [this out](http://stringtopathgeometry.codeplex.com/) which works with WinRT even though it was made for SL2 since WinRT is based on SL.

Comment: I never proceeded to trying it out @ChrisW. and i'll possibly delete this if it's not helpful to others, unless you'd like to post it as an answer.